# Customize hr element

Tags: css

[image]

Anyone know how to write the hr exactly same as the picture above? I tried to put `clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 5% 0)` but also cannot work

```css
.divider {
        color:#1D0000;
        display: flex;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 1em -1em;
    }
.divider:before,
.divider:after {
    content: "";
    flex: 1;
    border:1px solid #1D0000;
    margin: 0 1em;
    clip-path: polygon(0 20%, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%, 5% 0)
}
```

```html
<h2 class="divider">Testing</h2>
```

Comment: should it be exactly <hr> tag? Otherwise you could create 2 different div for left and right side and style it using transform rotate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `transform: skew()`?

```css
.divider {
  color: #1D0000;
  display: flex;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1em -1em;
}

.divider::before,
.divider::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
  height: 4px;
  border-top: 1px solid #1D0000;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
.divider::before {
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  border-right: 3px solid #1D0000;
}
.divider::after {
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
  border-left: 3px solid #1D0000;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="divider">Game List</h2>
```